# spark session isolation in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, isolation

I am using databricks and running multiple notebooks on the same cluster. Each notebook represents a task which requires specific task settings.

Now when i change the spark settings on a notebook, it seems this gets applied at the cluster level and the same change happens for the spark session on the other notebook.

But this is not what i want, i want to be able to provide different spark setting for each notebook on the same cluster

I have tried setting the `spark.databricks.session.share` to `false` but still the same issue persists.

Is this possible in Databricks?

Comment: Are you calling one notebook from another? Session isolation should be enabled by default, but if you call another notebook it will share same session as its caller.

Comment: No I have 2 independent notebooks attached to the same cluster

Comment: So, as far as I know all these sessions share same `SparkContext`. You are able to have per session configuration of `spark.sql` configs, but I'm not sure what exact config you want to change?

Comment: I want to have number of executors, number of partitions ( shuffle partitions) and executor memory configured differently for the 2 notebooks which are running at the same time